# List Comprehension Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to use list comprehension to print only strings that contain a substring `.pdf`.

Here is the line of code causing the syntax error.

```
list_of_files = [x if ".pdf" in x for x in list_of_files]
```

The list `list_of_files` contains `.pdf` and `.docx` files for reference. They are gathered using `os.listdir`.

This `for` loop works fine but I would much rather use list comprehension.

```
for x in list_of_files:
    if ".pdf" in x:
        print(x)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: "This for loop works fine but I would much rather use list comprehension" <- why?  Are are you building a `list`?

Comment: I'm building the list so I can open `.pdf` files if a user clicks on a `tkinter` button

Comment: Your order of arguments is incorrect, second, `print` returns `None`, so you are creating a list of `None`

Comment: But your non-for loop version doesn't make a list, it just prints things.  Do you want to select only elements of the list which have `.pdf` in them (or, better, end with `.pdf`?)

Comment: I only added the print statement so it would be more like my for loop at the bottom. I removed it to cause less confusion

Comment: would a lambda expression actually work with the list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `print(x)`. Just `x` would get the job done.

```
list_of_files = ['test.pdf','doc.docx','yolo.pdf']
pdfs = [x for x in list_of_files if '.pdf' in x]
print(pdfs)
```

Output:

```
['test.pdf', 'yolo.pdf']
```

`if` condition needs to be specified after the `for` loop if you need to filter your list (which is what you are trying to do). If you just need conditionals to check for items, you can use `if with else` before the `for` loop. An `if` before the loop absolutely requires an `else`.

```
pdfs = [x if '.pdf' in x else 'Not pdf' for x in list_of_files]
print(pdfs)
['test.pdf', 'Not pdf', 'yolo.pdf']
```

Comment: This works. I guess the `if` statement has to go after the loop.

Comment: The conditional test should come after the for loop in your comprehension. If you are checking the conditional before the for loop you need to specify else condition for it to work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I will mark your answer as correct when I can

Answer (score 1):

`print(list(x for x in list_of_files if '.pdf' in x))`

Comment: I like this answer which includes the print command. I think the print(x) was simply to read the file name though whilst the OP is testing.

Answer (score 1):

`pdf_files = [x for x in file_list if ".pdf" in x]`

Your if statement needs to be at the end because that's when it's evaluated logically. I'm not sure if the if statement can work at the start, I just don't see it making sense to have the if statement before you expand the list object into individual values.

As pointed out in the accepted answer, you can have if at the beginning of a list comprehension  loop, however, you're required to provide an else statement at the end (to catch any stragglers). In this case it would not be suitable as you only want to include the values in the new list to contain .pdf and discard the others.